# Evaluating a matrix Pick function via its integral representation

Tags: cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis

In the proof of Theorem 3.1 of the paper *[Inequalities for M-matrices](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088008817334)*, Ando evaluates a matrix function (see equation boxed in orange below) via an integral representation  of a Pick function (see Lemma 3.1):

[image: Ando excerpt]

A well-known faulty argument for the Cayley–Hamilton theorem is to replace $t$ with $B$ in the characteristic polynomial $p(t) := \det (tI - B)$. And, obviously, one can not replace $t$ with $A$ to evaluate $p[A]$. Hopefully, this motivates the following:

**Question:** What is the justification for being able to evaluate $f[A]$ in this manner?

Ando provides the definition of a matrix function via the Cauchy integral formula on p. 300, but this doesn't seem to be of much help.

Comment: Isn't this just holomorphic functional calculus for a Banach algebra (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus ) in the special case of the algebra ${\mathbb M}_n$?

Comment: I see that the top of the image you've provided/quoted mentions holomorphic functional calculus. Is your question about why this is valid in general, or about the specific formula in the box in orange?

Comment: @YemonChoi: the article you link justifies replacing z with A in the Cauchy integral formula—my question is specifically for the equation boxed in orange.